# Merge Word documents using XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Aloha,

I have two .docx files I would like to merge (simply put one document after the other) on my server. Between the documents, I would like to insert some meta information from my backend system (such as author and date; all information are specified in an external .xml file)

I have already found out, that an XSLT processor cannot parse a .doc or .docx file because the format is binary. One possibility would be to use the Word .xml extension.

I would like to know whether it is possible to convert the input .docx file to the .xml word format and then apply my changes. It is no problem to run the transformations on the .xml word file but as explained above taking the docx file as input fails.

And supposed I am able to run my transformations, how can I convert the word .xml file back to a docx file (the client only wants to work with .docx files and not with .xml files).

Is XSLT appropriate for this task or is there a 'better technology'?

I am running XSLT 1.0.

Cheers

Comment: Change the .docx to a .zip extension and you will be able to see how the file is laid out. Then you can decide if you want to do it this way. I've had good success using XSLT with 2003 .xml excel format. There are big differences between the 2003 .xml and the other .xml format in the drop down box

Comment: Another thing. I've used Powershell to change the format of Excel files, I assume the same thing can be done for Word. If you are interested I can try to put an answer together. If you don't want to you powershell you should be able to translate it to the COM language of your choice

Comment: Using powershell seems to be a very good option since I'm running Windows Server 2008 R2. Can you post some details so I can mark your answer as the correct one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will probably need a bit of work to modify for your needs, and there might be a bug or two in it, but it should get you started down the right path.
Take a look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839952.aspx and try the different XML options to decide which one works best for you.

```
param(
    [string]$Filename,
    [string]$StyleSheet,
    [string]$outputFile
)

$WordApp = New-Object -ComObject Word.application

if (![System.IO.Path]::IsPathRooted($FileName)){
    $Filename = Join-Path $pwd $FileName
}

$Document = $WordApp.Documents.Open($Filename, 2, $true) # Read only

$newFilename = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($filename, "xml")

if (Test-Path $newFilename){
    Remove-Item $newFilename
}

#http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839952.aspx
$Document.SaveAs($newFilename, [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat]::wdFormatXMLDocument)
$Document.Close()

$xslt = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform;
$xslt.Load($StyleSheet, $null, $null);
$xslt.Transform( $newFilename, $outputFile );


$WordApp.Quit()
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($WordApp) | Out-Null
```